# Polling data from restful webservice with "keepalive" connection

Tags: java, android, http, rest

i'm developing an android application that fetches data from a restful web service.

i was thinking about the best way to implement this, my code is working but i'm sure it can be optimized.
here's my current code state:
i'm calling the restResource from a service using a scheduler. 
the bad part is opening and closing connection on every request.
(the rest resource keeps realtime data( i have to fetch it every second), when it's empty it returns an empty array)

```
        httpResponse = client.execute(request);
        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

            response = convertStreamToString(instream);

            instream.close();
        }
```

how to make use of the keepalive header returned with the response?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before using long-polling, in which my RESTful call blocks until either there is a timeout or it has something to reply with.  Either way, the calling client would re-call the RESTful service again on either response (timeout or valid).

I am not sure how to you could use the keepalive header, but it seems like what you would do is send it, and then simply keep the connection open.  In your server-side java code, you would get the output buffer for the response and start sending stuff down.  On the client side, get the input buffer (not sure how this happens in Android, but I am under the impression its Java code, so there are loads of ways you can do any of this) and start reading.  At some point I would think you would need to force the connection close, just because you don't want to keep it open indefinately.

Again, I have never tried it this way, so I don't know.  Also, I am not sure if this breaks some unspoken laws of RESTful services.  I have never read anything to contradict this approach.

Comment: Thank you @CodeChimp, lets say i want to keep it indefinitely, how can i read the response over and over again ? as i remember the content gets consumed after the first time. what is the proper way in java to keep a connection open and  periodically read the response multiple times ?

Comment: I think you would want to grab the OutputStream and just not close it.  As long as its open, the connection would be open.  Keep in mind, the OutputStream you get from the HttpServletResponse is linked, ultimately, to the Socket, so if you close it, you close the socket.  This goes for both sides.